# Program not calculating correctly

Tags: c#

I have two calculations that are correct, the parts and the tax, but the Service and labor and the total is wrong. Any insight into what I overlooked would be appreciated.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



     //method for calculating oil and lube charges
        private int OilLubeCharges()
        {
            int total = 0;

            //if oil is checked, add 28 to total
            if (chkOilChange.Checked)
            {
                total += 26;
            }

             //if lube is checked, add 18 to total
            if (chkLube.Checked)
            {
                total += 18;
                return total;
            }
           //If nothing is checked return 0
            else
            {
                return total;
            }
         }

     //method for calculating Flushes
     private int FlushCharges()
     {
         //define local variable
         int total = 0;

         //if radiator is checked, add 30 to total
         if (chkRadiator.Checked)
         {
             total += 30;

             //if transmission is checked, add 80 to total
             if (chkTransmission.Checked)
             {
                 total += 80;
                 return total;
             }
                 //if nothing is checked return 0
             else
             {
                 return total;
             }
         }
         //if nothing is checked return 0
         else
         {
             return total;
         }
      }

     private int MiscCharges()
     {
         //define local variable
         int total = 0;
         //if inspection is checked, add to total
         if (chkInspection.Checked)
         {
             total += 15;
         }

         //if replace muffler is checked, add 100 to total
         if (chkMuffler.Checked)
         {
             total += 100;
         }

         //if tire rotation is checked, add 20 to total
         if (chkTire.Checked)
         {
             total += 20;
             return total;
         }
         //if nothing is checked return 0
         else
         {
             return total;
         }
     }
     //calculate the total for the other charges
     private int OtherCharges()
     {
         int total = 0;
         int labor;
         decimal parts;

        if (int.TryParse(txtLabor.Text, out labor))
         {
             total = labor;
         }

         if (decimal.TryParse(txtParts.Text, out parts))
         {
             txtPartsTotal.Text = parts.ToString("c"); 
             return total;
         }

         else
         {
             return total;
         }

     }

     private decimal TaxCharges()
     {
         decimal addTax;
         string parts = txtParts.Text;
          addTax = Convert.ToDecimal(parts) * 0.06m;
          txtTax.Text = addTax.ToString("c");
          return addTax;
    }

     private decimal TotalCharges()
     {
         decimal total;
         decimal serviceAndLabor;
         total = OtherCharges() + MiscCharges() + OilLubeCharges() + FlushCharges() + TaxCharges();
         txtTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");


         serviceAndLabor = MiscCharges() + OilLubeCharges() + FlushCharges() + OtherCharges();
         txtServiceAndLabor.Text = serviceAndLabor.ToString("c");

         return total;


     }


    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OilLubeCharges();
        FlushCharges();
        MiscCharges();
        OtherCharges();
        TaxCharges();
        TotalCharges();
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }


    }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are the actual calculations that go wrong? What are input values, what is the expected output, what is the actual output. You should make it as easy for people to find the problem as possible, without digging through 3 pages of source code.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx)? What is your expected output and what is being output instead?

Comment: Sorry, the specific calculations are messed up in the total calculations method. The checkboxes that get checked for some reason don't add up correctly. Also, the expected output depends on what the user selects. I have tried debugging, and it hasn't really helped.

Comment: Then post a specific example of user input, what the expected output would be and what is being output instead.

Comment: Here is a picture of the program running. https://gyazo.com/6512b0f35a28e71a6b8eccf677eb466e The expected total output with what was selected should be: $286.60, but as you can see it is only $146.60. The service and labor should be: $276, but it's only 146.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the middle of all those "magic numbers" I would draw your attention to this code snippet

```
//if oil is checked, add 28 to total
if (chkOilChange.Checked)
{
    total += 26;
}
```

You want to add 28 to the total but have only added 26

Comment: It is actually supposed to be 26, I had my comment wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my old code I had an if statement nested into another one when it shouldn't have been. On top of that I returned something in the middle of my method, so it was never reaching one statement.

```
 //if radiator is checked, add 30 to total
     if (chkRadiator.Checked)
     {
         total += 30;

         //if transmission is checked, add 80 to total
         if (chkTransmission.Checked)
         {
             total += 80;
             return total;
         }
             //if nothing is checked return 0
         else
         {
             return total;
         }
     }
     //if nothing is checked return 0
     else
     {
         return total;
     }
```